# How are these two XPath expressions different?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm parsing a website using XPath. I've got two queries, one which finds the node I'm looking for:

```
//td[.//text()[contains(., "Date Filed:")]]
```

And one which doesn't:

```
//td[contains(.//text(), "Date Filed:")]
```

I don't understand how these are different. I'd read them both to mean, "Find `td` nodes which have a descendant text node containing `Date Filed`."

Can anybody explain how these are different?

Here's the HTML, though I don't think it's relevant to the question:

```
<td width="40%" valign="top">
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <b>Date Filed:</b> 11/13/2008<br>
    <b>Jury Demand: </b> No<br><br>
    <br><b>Date Terminated: </b><br>
    <br><b>Date Reopened: </b><br>
    <br><b>Does this action raise an issue of constitutionality?: </b>Y<br>
</td>
```

(Don't look at me that way. I didn't make the website, the U.S. Gov't did.)

Comment: I feel like this is a general question, but I don't know the terms to make it one. Once somebody explains this, I'll update the title and whatnot so others can find it.

Answer (score 2):

That is how string conversion works in XPath:
In the second query `contains(.//text(), "Date Filed:")` you call `contains` function. It accepts two arguments of type string, you first parameter `.//text()` is `node-set` datatype, which means `string` function gets called internally to convert list of nodes to `string`. In this case `string(.//text())` returns only first text node. If you change your second query to this: `//td[contains(., "Date Filed:")]` it will select the wanted `td`.

Comment: Thanks. So lesson is, `contains` will just silently apply to the first node in a node-set?

Comment: @mlissner, exactly, here is the w3 reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string _A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the node in the node-set that is first in document order._

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 1.0, if you supply a node-set to a function like `contains()` that expects a string, it uses the string-value of the first node in the node-set (in document order).

In XPath 2.0 and later versions, if you supply a node-set to a function like `contains()` that expects a string, the node-set is atomized, and if the result contains more than one string (which will normally be the case when more than one node is selected), then you get a type error XPTY0004.

When you ask questions about XSLT or XPath on StackOverflow, please always say which version you are talking about.